# How do I get apache (on Ubuntu 22.04) to allow me access via port 5443 (ie not with ports 80 or 443)

Tags: apache-2.4, port

Hi I know this question has been asked before but I've tried all the suggestions and I still can't get apache to show the 'it works' page.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on a remote vps. If I don't use port 5443 (ie I just enter myurl) I get the Apache 'it works' page.  I've set ufw to allow 5443 tcp and udp.
I've added Listen 5443 to ports.conf.
I've tried changing <VirtualHost *:80>  to <VirtualHost *:80 *:5443>
I've done the same for  443 (<VirtualHost *:443 *:5443> and finally I've tried setting up a separate virtual host with port 5443 as its port.
I really can't think of anything else I can do.  Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Below is the text of the separate virtual host file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:5443> 

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName myserver.org.uk
    ServerAlias www.myserver.org.uk
    DocumentRoot /path/to/directory

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /path/to/directory>
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.org.uk/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.org.uk/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you encounter when you try to reach that port?

Comment: It just times out viz 'The connection has timed out'

Comment: A timeout indicates a firewall issue. Check for another firewall outside of your server.

Comment: Thanks for that.  There is a router between me and www.  I've never looked, but it might have its own firewall.

Comment: Gerald:  I can't thank you enough for this bit of information.  It turns out that although I've got a vps with its own firewall I still have to get my isp to open the ports.  This would never have crossed my mind without your comment above.  It now works! Thankyou :)